# devexpress spline chart, get y axis value from x axis value

Tags: c#, devexpress

i draw a line chart from a list of points using devexpress c#

i have a list values of x-axis value

and i want to calculate y-axis value from any x-axis value of this list

please help me. Thank you

Comment: Could you please share your [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or update your question with other effort you made

Answer (score 0):

ChartControl API does not include a method to evaluate an arbitrary Spline point value because it uses the GDI+ methods to draw a Bezier curve (see the [following](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t560863/how-to-retrieve-interpolated-spline-points-data) ticket for additional information).

In this scenario, it is better to implement a domain-specific function for nonlinear analysis and calculate the required value manually.